# Using Telerik in asp.net mvc - Multiselect

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-mvc

Im new to asp.net mvc, and im trying telerik on a project for a client.

I'm trying to add [this](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/multiselect/template) to my project and i get the Select customers box with a infinite loading icon rotating.

Something like this:

[image]

I would like to know how i "bind" data to the control so i display a list of users like in their website example.

so far i tried creating this method in the HomeController

```
public ActionResult GetCustomers([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{    
    string jstring = "[{\"CustomerID\": \"ALFKI\", \"ContactName\": \"Maria Anders\" ,\"CompanyName\": \"Alfreds Futterkiste\"}]";

    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<userTest>>(jstring);
    return Json(obj);
}
```

and i have this class:

```
public class userTest
{
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my index.cshtml:

```
<div class="demo-section">
    <h3 class="title">Select customers</h3>
    @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
          .Name("customers")
          .DataTextField("ContactName")
          .DataValueField("CustomerID")
          .DataSource(source =>
          {
              source.Read(read =>
              {
                  read.Action("GetCustomers", "Home");
              });
          })
          .Height(300)
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 400px" })
          ...
          .ItemTemplate("<span class=\"k-state-default\"><img src=\"" + Url.Content("http://yarris.design/images/userCentered.png") +" /> </span>" + "<span class=\"k-state-default\"><h3>#: data.ContactName #</h3><p>#: data.CompanyName #</p></span>")
          .TagTemplate("<img class=\"tag-image\" src=\"" +
          Url.Content("http://yarris.design/images/userCentered.png") +
          "\" alt=\"\" />" +
          "#: data.ContactName #")
    )
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var customers = $("#customers").data("kendoMultiSelect");
        customers.wrapper.attr("id", "customers-wrapper");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, you don't need that `dataSourceRequest` as a parameter. You need to return a Json with the dataTextField and the DataValueField.

I don't know what is returned to your `obj` variable, so the last line (with linq) must not match exactly what's in it, but I think you'll get the point.

```
public ActionResult GetCustomers()
{
    string jstring = "[{\"CustomerID\": \"ALFKI\", \"ContactName\": \"Maria Anders\" ,\"CompanyName\": \"Alfreds Futterkiste\"}]";
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<userTest>>(jstring);
    return Json(obj.Select(s => new userTest { ContactName = s.ContactName, CustomerID = s.CustomerID }).Distinct(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: ah, ok, im able to see something now :) still looking a bit strange visually , but at least it shows information :), thanks for the help

Comment: Strange visually? But is the data you expected to see in the DDL there?

Comment: http://oi62.tinypic.com/mtayko.jpg one of the fields is null

Comment: oh nvm, just noticed the error, i was missing  CompanyName = s.CompanyName in the C# code